# Tableau - How to calculate date/time difference and result in full date/time?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to calculate a difference between connection time and disconnected time. See image below. But DATEPART formula that I'm using only allows me to use one parameter (hour, minute, second,...)

However, as in the image, I have an ID where disconnection at 3/1/17 2:35:22PM and connection back at 3/2/17 1:59:38 PM

Ideal Response: 23 hours, 24 minutes and 16 seconds

but using the formula:

```
ZN(LOOKUP(ATTR(DATEPART('minute', [Disconnected At])),-1)-(ATTR(DATEPART('minute', [Connected At]))))
```

it isn't doing the trick.

Could someone help me to achieve my ideal response? Or similar result that would give me the completeness of date and time?

Thank You

[Tableau ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP3x6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DATEDIFF by seconds between your two dates. Then create a calc field as follows:

```
//replace [Seconds] with whatever field has the number of seconds in it
//and use a custom number format of 00:00:00:00 (drop the first 0 to get rid of leading 0's for days)
IIF([Seconds] % 60 == 60,0,[Seconds] % 60)// seconds
+ IIF(INT([Seconds]/60) %60 == 60, 0, INT([Seconds]/60) %60) * 100 //minutes
+ IIF(INT([Seconds]/3600) % 24 == 0, 0, INT([Seconds]/3600) % 24) * 10000 //hours
+ INT([Seconds]/86400) * 1000000 // days
```

for more information, check out this blog post where I got this from. http://drawingwithnumbers.artisart.org/formatting-time-durations/